# Abort upload with UIkits Upload Component?

Tags: javascript, getuikit

The title says it all. How can I abort the upload with UIKits Upload Component?

I'm trying to abort the upload in the `beforeAll` callback but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {
    url: '',
    multiple: false,
    mime: 'audio/*',
    allow: '*.mp3',

    beforeAll: function () {
      return false; // <--- Why does it not return/abort?
      });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source code. The [return value from `beforeAll` isn't used](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/37aa583240be989b0f420bf5e5023ff9493b1527/src/js/components/upload.js#L130).

The best option I see to abort the request is to get hang of the `XMLHttpRequest` object and call `abort()` on it:

```js
UIkit.upload(".js-upload", { 
  // ...
  loadStart: function (e) {
    e.target.abort();
  },
  abort: function (e) {
    // clean up after abort
  }
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the only way to actually abort the upload. I dont understand how we're supposed to do any error handling with this concept from UIkit.

Comment: You have [`fail` and `error` callbacks](https://getuikit.com/docs/upload#component-options) for invalid input and failed xhr request. But aborting the upload doesn't seem to be a major use-case...

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with the latest version unfortunately.